# Get original URL of a saved webpage

Tags: python, url, python-3.x, web-scraping, lxml

I am using Python and lxml library to parse a saved webpage.

The docinfo of a saved webpage shows the disk location of a saved webpage.

```
storedHtmlDoc.docinfo.URL
```

Is there any way to extract the original URl from the saved page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not stored somewhere yourself the URL of the downloaded page, it's not available to you.

If you can control the downloading process, you could put the URL of the downloaded page inside a META tag of the page.

Comment: OK. I have that liberty. I am using `urllib.request` to fetch the webpage, and lxml to parse (and maybe manipulate) it. How do you suggest I add a META tag to the fetched webpage?

Comment: I know using regexes for HTML is not a very good idea, but you could find opening `<head>` tag and insert right after it something like `<meta downloaded-from="http://*******">`. I am not aware of a standard `META` tag for storing original URLs, but in your case having a non standard tag should not break anything.

Comment: Another more simple way is to add a comment at the end of the file like: `<!-- Downloaded from http://******* -->`. But then, i am not sure you can get then URL using lxml.

Comment: Following your advice, I wrote a function that grabs the `<head>` tag from an HTML document, and adds a `<meta name='originalUrl' content='URI'>` tag to it. Thanks.